# How to use the access token from uber api in accessing trip history

Tags: php, json, curl, oauth-2.0, uber-api

I am trying the **Uber API** and have got the following response output from the Uber API which has the **Access Token** :

```
{"last_authenticated":0,"access_token":"KQ.eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoyLCJpZCI6IlpOTjJ0ZjVMUzFpcW5JbVEvAdffgfgmc9PfsfsZXNffsdfdsfsdf5MDY4OTEsaW5lX2tleV9pZCI6Ik1RPT0iLCJwaXfCI6MX0.i3fnzPo61qO29IyOcs5OqfqQ_KEYtxs","expires_in":2592000,"token_type":"Bearer","scope":"history history_lite places profile ride_widgets","refresh_token":"QrerwerwrSAsdgdgg5532ADPkOmzXEiATEoATIBMQ.skNozSMCJobAl_vTDfPo2GEi_D0h1daHm6YQXCwgCws.t-NMldx56v2Pe1J_sNTxrNqjBlfsfsdfsfs6Lq8QxT29FM"}
```

Next I want to use CURL as mentioned below to access the trip history which is documented at :  https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/history-get

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>' \
     -H 'Accept-Language: en_US' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     'https://api.uber.com/v1.2/history'
```

but I am unsure on how or **where to set the access token for the curl request** which will respond with the trip history as json output.

Comment: Now we have your tokens and will use them)))))

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code

Comment: @u_mulder Please go ahead and use these :-) these are not the actual ones..  i had replaced these tokens with random values before posting in open forum... Best of Luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to using curl to php converter from here https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

here is the result

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/history");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer ".$token;
$headers[] = "Accept-Language: en_US";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); //For https
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);//For https
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);


print_r($result);
```

Comment: How do i get the value of access token in $token from the redirect uri which returns a json response which includes access token apart from other key and values also..

Comment: So you don't know how to work with json strings? Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php

Comment: @u_mulder i know about parsing json.. My point is that the json string which contains the access token is shown as response by the url. I am unable to capture that json output in any variable. $data = fetchUrl('https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token', $_GET['code']); returns the json.. I need to capture this json in a variable. get the acess token .. and pass on to the next curl

Comment: Please then create a new question or edit this one. Because the problem you encounter has nothing with what's described in question now.

Comment: please update your question with additional data or scripts you tried